# why spread operator working this way? Please explan

Tags: javascript

Why did the object inside another object value got changed(x.address.city) and why did the name value changed?

why **y** address field changed to Pune and not the same worked for name?

```js
const x = {
  name: "ABC",
  email: "ac@gmail.com",
  mob: "12345",
  address: {
    city: "Mumbai",
    state: "Maharastra"
  }
};
const y = { ...x }
x.name = "XYZ";
console.log(x.name, y.name);
x.address.city = "Pune";
console.log(x.address.city, y.address.city);
```

**Output**:

```
XYZ ABC 
Pune Pune
```

Comment: Nested objects are not deep copied. Their reference is copied. To deep clone an object, you can use the spread syntax as: `{ ...x, address: { ...x.address } }`

Comment: You could do `const y = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(x));`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen what will this do?

Comment: It will make a deep clone as you want

Answer (score 2):

The spread operator in `JavaScript` does not do a deep copy of the objects, so both objects will keep a reference to the same `address` object. If you want to make a deep copy, consider using the `structuredClone()`

Official docs: [Structured Clone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone)

Browser Support: [Browser Support](https://caniuse.com/?search=structuredClone)

Comment: The question is [a dupe](https://www.google.com/search?q=deep+clone+object+javascript+site:stackoverflow.com).

Comment: why dupe @mplungjan ? It was one of my doubt during interview days.

Comment: @Ramanjeet Dupe: Duplicate question with many answers

Comment: I understand @mplungjan but at that time I didn't get one.